# Programmatically create more workers at run-time by using Django_rq

Tags: python-3.x, django, background-process, django-rq

I want to increase the number of workers in Django project by using Django_rq(Redis Queue) the problem is that I have to manually start each worker to complete the process in short time is their any way I can increase the number of workers or their number of process at the run time by using Django_rq?

The problem is that queue which has large data takes time more even after optimization of code and cannot allow the other ids to processed until its queue with large data complete . It puts other ids in queue until large queue with data is completed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We automatically start 3 workers. All of them serve the "high" priority queue, 2 of them the "default" one, an one of then the "low" priority queue. It's very possible that the worker processes run in a separate container / vm, so there is no one exclusive answer. If you'd like to run these in the same container /vm, you could this solution https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/689#issuecomment-1125403879